# Launching development instances or HDD drives using bigtable python

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am using the python Bigtable api to manage my bigtable instances. It has been useful so far but one shortcoming I have found is it does not let me set the instance type or the disk type of my instances, so I can only launch production instance with SSD drives (no development instances or HDD drives). Does anybody have a solution to this or am I going to have to write a wrapper around gcloud?

Answer (score 2):

Hi thanks for pointing this out and sorry you ran into this issue.

The client is actually fully open source. It would be very helpful if you could file an issue or feature request here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues

There's actually a note about the missing storage type selection in the code here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigtable/google/cloud/bigtable/instance.py

If you are so inclined you are also of course welcome to submit a patch as per the instructions here: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst

Comment: I see you filed the issue, thanks! Linking it here for anyone else following along:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3344